# Get the file with the maximum month year

Tags: command-line

I have a requirement to get the file with the maximum month year.

We have files in a directory as below:

```
Zmx_0416_control.txt
Zmx_0316_control.txt
```

Now from these files, I need to get the file `Zmx_0416_control.txt` as it belongs to Apr 2016.

I need a Unix command to identify the max file (`Zmx_0416_control.txt`)  from the list of files.

Comment: Please tell us what you already tried.

Comment: Are they all called Zmx_MMYY_control.txt? Because `ls` automatically sorts, and you could just do `ls | tail -1` to get the most recent

Comment: @mmusante: If it was YYMM, yes, but not with MMYY.

Comment: @Sukminder: Is it possible to use LC_LOCALE to overcome this

Comment: @frams: How would that come to be?

Comment: @Sukminder: I have no idea. However, if there is a way to treat the file names as time format "Zmx_%m%y_control.txt", though weird, I think problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

not so elegent solution:

convert %m%y to 100*y+m, eg: 0416->1604, then compare by numeric value.

```
for i in Z*
do
  # convert %m%y to 100*y+m
  current=$((100 * $(echo "$i"|cut -c 7-8) + $(echo "$i"|cut -c 5-6)))
  if [[ $current > $max ]]; then
    max=$current
    maxstr=$i
  fi
done

echo $maxstr
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sort`:

```
ls Zmx* | sort -k 1.7n -k 1.5,1.6n
```

or

```
ls Zmx* | sort -t _ -k 2.3n -k 2,2.2n
```

With a concluding `| tail -1`

From GNU sort:

- [`comparison`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#index-sort_0027s-last_002dresort-comparison):

  > “[…] A pair of lines is compared as follows: sort compares each pair of fields, in the order specified on the command line, according to the associated ordering options, until a difference is found or no fields are left. […]”
- [`index-sort-field`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#index-sort-field)

Also see [POSIX sort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).

Comment: nice answer! missing tail -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two variables to keep the file name and portion to compare:

```
max=; f=; { for i in *.txt; do d="$(cut -d_ -f2 <<<"$i")"; \
  d_s="$(sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)/\2\1/' <<<"$d")"; \
    [ "$d_s" -gt "$max" ] && max="$d_s" && f="$i"; done ;} && echo "$f"
```

- `max` contains the current maximum while traversing through file names
- `f` contains the file name while traversing
- `cut` takes the second field separated by `_`
- `sed` is used to swap the month and year for comparison

**Example:**

```
$ ls -1                                                                                                                                                                      
foobar
Zmx_0316_control.txt
Zmx_0416_control.txt
Zmx_0716_control.txt

$ max=; f=; { for i in *.txt; do d="$(cut -d_ -f2 <<<"$i")"; d_s="$(sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)/\2\1/' <<<"$d")"; [ "$d_s" -gt "$max" ] && max="$d_s" && f="$i"; done ;} && echo "$f"
Zmx_0716_control.txt
```